# reading csv with pandas and specifying columns names

Tags: pandas, csv

I'm trying to import data form a csv file using pandas:

```
data=pd.read_csv("data.csv")
```

this seems to work fine. Next I would like to specify columns' names with

```
data.columns = ['X', 'Y']
```

so that i can plot it later. And here the problem comes:

```
File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'X'
```

csv file has the following format

```
   X   Y    
  20   120  
  25   145  
  41   160  
  62   301
...
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What code return error?

Comment: data.columns = ['X', 'Y'] gives error above

Comment: hmmm, what is `print (data.columns)` before `data.columns = ['X', 'Y']` ?

Comment: it gives

Index(['  X   Y    '], dtype='object')

Comment: I think there is separator whitespace, so need `data=pd.read_csv("data.csv", delim_whitespace=True)` and omit `data.columns = ['X', 'Y']`

Comment: Great this works now! Thank a lot!
I tried to use sep='  ', and delim='  ', but those didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to import a "space" separated DataFrame. As said @jezrael in comments, you should use:

```
data=pd.read_csv("data.csv", delim_whitespace=True)
```

From the [official doc](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#csv-text-files):

> delim_whitespace : boolean, default False
>
> Equivalent to setting sep='\s+'. 
>   If this option is set to True, nothing should be passed in for the delimiter parameter.

More over, if you want to specify column names (which is your question):

Again from the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) you can see that you should either :

- use `names` argument to specify the name that the columns should take.
- use `header` argument to tell python that the first line (index 0) should be parsed as the colnames

So to resume, you should be able to use any of the three statements:

```
data = pandas.csv("data.csv", delim_whitespace=True, names=["X","Y"])

data = pandas.csv("data.csv", delim_whitespace=True, header=0)

data = pandas.csv("data.csv", sep="\s+")
```

> Concerning `header` parameter:
>
> Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the data. Default behavior is to infer the column names
>   if no names are passed the behavior is identical to header=0 and column names are inferred from the first line of the file
>
> Note that this parameter ignores commented lines and empty lines if skip_blank_lines=True, so header=0 denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file